# Disable TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 using httpd CentOS7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ssl, https, apache-virtualhost

I'm trying to disable TLS 1.0/1.1 for PCI Compliance, but having problems.

Running CentOS 7 / Apache 2.4.6

The Server is setup with multiple hosts.
All the documentation I've found is similar but nothing seems to work.

In /etc/httpd/conf.d (it currently has set)

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

Also in the /etc/httpd/sitnamefqdn.conf (specific for the domain)

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

And just because I've read this about letsencrypt (even though not active)
/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

I have restarted httpd, and rebooted just to make sure, nothing seems to take.

If you use the site: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest I'm still getting..

```
This server is vulnerable to the POODLE attack. If possible, disable SSL 3 to mitigate. Grade capped to C.   
This server accepts RC4 cipher, but only with older protocols. Grade capped to B.  
This server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference browsers. Grade capped to B.  
This server supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1. Grade capped to B. 

Protocols
TLS 1.3 No
TLS 1.2 Yes
TLS 1.1 Yes
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3   INSECURE    Yes
SSL 2   No
```

Comment: how do you know it's not working?

Comment: Good point.. I edited the post:  Use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest.   And just to clarity, the results are not Cached.

Comment: Also to note: Using httpd-2.4.6-99.el7.centos.1.x86_64

Comment: These options are working for me on same releases (centos/httpd). Did you check/change all SSLProtocol lines in httpd conf directories ?

Comment: @tonioc Yes all edited with the exception of some in an "old" directory inside that folder.  Will it reach in and grab those also?  Is there some way to see exactly what files are being read as part of the init?  There are two virtual servers (same ip) here, and so I've added it inside the VirtualServer section for those.